# I want to implement a File Explorer, How can I read file's icon and display them?

Tags: windows, icons, windows-explorer

I want to implement a File Explorer, It is different from a normal file explorer, it first scan file system and store information into database, them read file system information from Database, and display them, I need to store the icons of the file, how can I do this? Is there any Windows APIs?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179(VS.85).aspx) can get a handle for the icon of a file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179(VS.85).aspx). [This](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHGetFileInfo) looks like a pretty good example for .NET.